# Trying to 'grep' links from downloaded html pages in bash shell environment without cut, sed, tr commands (only e/grep)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tr

In Linux shell, I am trying to return links to JPG files from the downloaded HTML script file. So far I only got to this point:

```
grep 'http://[:print:]*.jpg' 'www_page.html'
```

I don't want to use auxiliary commands like 'tr', 'cut', 'sed' etc...'lynx' is okay!

Comment: I need to build a house but I only want to use this feather. No hammers or saws or anything. Just a feather. Can anyone help? :-) Isn't life hard enough without introducing arbitrary restrictions? I'm afraid I have to close-vote as too localised since this is unlikely to help anyone else in the future (presumably we won't ever get to a point where `grep` is the only text processing tool we have the source code for).

Comment: And the question is? I'd suggest using perl, but that would be just like the other useful tools you seem to want to avoid.

Comment: If you can actually manage to make a pattern that matches only the desired kinds of URLs, you could use `grep -o`, but... good luck. All kinds of ways for your regex to go wrong if the HTML isn't pretty.

Comment: It's likely that knowing ***why*** you don't want to use "auxiliary commands" would help us give you better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Using grep alone without massaging the file is doable but not recommended as many have pointed out in the comments.

If you can loosen up your requirements a bit then you can use [html tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to massage the downloaded HTML file so that each html entities are on a single line so that the regular expression can be simpler like you wanted, something like this:

```
$ tidy file.html|grep -o 'http://[[:print:]]*.jpg'
```

Note the use of "-o" option to grep to print only the matching part of the input

Comment: If the input is already tidy enough, the grep command is useful in its own right.

Comment: why the double square brackets? whats the difference betweeen `[:print:]*` and `[[:print:]]*`? What about `[[:print:]*]` ?

Comment: @Sudhi `[[:print:]]` means all printable characters in bracket expression. `[:print:]` means any of the characters ':', 'p', 'r', 'i', 'n', and 't'.